# How do I prove that Jetty 9 SelectChannelConnector timeouts work?

Tags: sockets, jetty

I am using Jetty 9.0.4 with Java 1.7.0 on Windows 7.

How do I prove that these timeouts work? Ideally I am looking for an integration unit test that will fail if they do not work.

```
org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector connector = new SelectChannelConnector();
connector.setMaxIdleTime(10_000);
connector.setSoLingerTime(10_000);
connector.setLowResourceMaxIdleTime(10_000);
```

I tried connecting to the http port in the following way, but it does not fail, just keeps on reading a byte every one minute. I expected it to fail because the max idle time was set to 10 seconds.

```
Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", port);
OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
outputStream.write("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: localhost\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n".getBytes());
outputStream.flush();
InputStream content = socket.getInputStream();
char aChar;
int bytesToReceive = 1000;
while((aChar = (char) content.read()) != -1 && bytesToReceive-- > 0) {
    System.out.println("Read '" + aChar + "' and going to sleep for a minute.");
    Thread.sleep(60_000);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jetty 9 does not have a SelectChannelConnector, nor is it under the org.mortbay package name...that is Jetty 6 code.

Jetty moved to the Eclipse Foundation from Jetty 7 onward and there have been over 150 releases since Jetty 6.

As for your test case, see this test code:

http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/jetty-server/src/test/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/ConnectorTimeoutTest.java